# Installing GRASS on Mac OS?

Tags: grass-gis, installation, mac

I am trying to Install Grass 7.2 on Mac OS 10.12.5 but received following error.

```
Last login: Tue Aug  1 18:47:28 on ttys000
macs-MacBook-Air:~ DrPallavi$ '/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/grass.sh'; exit
Rebuilding Addon HTML manual pages index...
Rebuilding Addon menu...
Python 2.7.10 found.
WARNING: Default locale settings are missing. GRASS running with C locale.
Starting GRASS GIS...
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libgrass_gis.7.0.5.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/gui/wxpython/gis_set.py", line 31, in <module>
    from core import globalvar
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/gui/wxpython/core/globalvar.py", line 29, in <module>
    from core.debug import Debug
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/gui/wxpython/core/debug.py", line 72, in <module>
    Debug = DebugMsg()
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/gui/wxpython/core/debug.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.SetLevel()
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/gui/wxpython/core/debug.py", line 43, in SetLevel
    self.debuglevel = int(grass.gisenv().get('WX_DEBUG', 0))
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 935, in gisenv
    s = read_command("g.gisenv", flags='n')
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 443, in read_command
    process = pipe_command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 418, in pipe_command
    return start_command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 356, in start_command
    if debug_level() > 0:
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 1519, in debug_level
    _debug_level = int(gisenv().get('DEBUG', 0))
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 935, in gisenv
    s = read_command("g.gisenv", flags='n')
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 446, in read_command
    return handle_errors(returncode, stdout, args, kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 313, in handle_errors
    returncode=returncode)
grass.exceptions.CalledModuleError: Module run None ['g.gisenv', '-n'] ended with error
Process ended with non-zero return code -6. See errors in the (error) output.
Error in GUI startup. If necessary, please report this error to the GRASS developers.
Switching to text mode now.

Hit RETURN to continue...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/grass70", line 1461, in <module>
    set_data()
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/grass70", line 682, in set_data
    gui_startup(grass_gui == 'gtext')
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/grass70", line 704, in gui_startup
    os.execlp(cmd_name, "-text")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 329, in execlp
    execvp(file, args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 346, in execvp
    _execvpe(file, args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 382, in _execvpe
    func(fullname, *argrest)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...none found.
```

Can you please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

There is an "image not found" error in your error message.

Probably you are lacking the installation of one or several "frameworks" which you can get from here:

http://grass.osgeo.org/download/software/mac-osx/

--> Install the required framework packages first